# waiting for client in TcpListener

Tags: c#, client-server

I am making a client server application using `System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener tcpl`, `System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream ns` and `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient echoserver;` in the server and using this code to keep the application responding:

```
while (!tcpl.Pending())
   Application.DoEvents();
echoserver = tcpl.AcceptTcpClient();
   ns = echoserver.GetStream();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   while ((i = ns.Read(recivedbytes, 0, recivedbytes.Length)) != 0)
   {
        ms.Write(recivedbytes, 0, i);
   }
}
```

I am waiting for client, but this makes too much load on the processor. Is there any other logic to do this without increasing load on the processor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
while (!tcpl.Pending())
   Application.DoEvents();
echoserver = tcpl.AcceptTcpClient();
```

the `while`-statement is actually redundant, because `AcceptTcpCLient()` is a blocking method. If you want your UI to be responsive, create a thread for your `TcpListener` and wait there using `AcceptTcpClient()` for incoming requests.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.acceptsocket.aspx) for further reference.